# How to create a linked server in Azure SQL MI to connect IBM AS400 i series

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ibm-midrange, linked-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

I want to fetch some data from AS400(IBM i series) from Azure sql Managed Instance. Currentlty I am not finding any solution to do that. Please suggest if there is any way to do this.

please help me getting the information to connect to IBM i series AS400 databases from Azure SQL Mnaged Instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you were on prem you should be able to do so through that piece of crap code called  [PolyBase](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/db2-odbc-polybase.rst).

Lately I have discovered that *that-piece-of-crap-code* is also [available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/955632/polybase-support-in-sql-server-managed-instance) in Azure SQL Managed Instances.

But believe me, the right way should be [this](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/ccc44856-3425-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f84) or creating an Azure Data Factory ETL process.